# How to make a private network?

Tags: networking, home-networking, private-network

An ethernet cable is coming to my room and I use static IP to connect to internet.
My IP is 150.XXX.XXX.7, subnet mask 255.255.255.0 , gateway 150.XXX.XXX.216. I want to connect ethernet on my router and make a private network so other devices can connect with DHCP (without setting static ip) using wifi or ethernet. How should I configure my router(ZTE ZXV10 H108L)? On what LAN port should I connect the ethernet cable coming in my room, should I bind all ports together? I will contact them soon for VPI/VCI.

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Looks like it's already configured.  Does it work?

Comment: If you're looking for the VPI/VCI number, you need to check your ISPs documentation, or contact them.

Comment: On what lan port should I connect the ethernet coming in my room, should I bind all ports together? I will contact them soon for VPI/VCI.

Comment: There's a lot of things that need clarifying. First off "private network" can mean a lot of things. If you want a network for your own use that isn't directly a part of the 150.x.x.x network then you don't want to use any of the LAN ports and, in fact, will need a different router. In that case, the network you want to plug the "public" network into would be the WAN port... which your router doesn't have because it's a DSL modem with an integrated router. Second, if you already have internet provided by this 150.x network why do you need DSL?

Answer (score 1):

You need a router with an Ethernet WAN port for this. Your ZTE ZXV10 H108L has an integrated DSL modem as its only WAN port, so it won't work in your situation.

Get a router with an Ethernet WAN port and connect its WAN port to the upstream Ethernet cable you have today.

Once you have a router with the right kind of WAN port for your needs, all the rest of the configuration will be pretty straightforward.